# Stored procedure not updating database. Saying im trying to insert null but I can't see where that is happening

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Having a little trouble with this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SiteUsers].[rtyfc_ChangePassword]
    (@userNm varchar(100),
     @pssWd nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE SiteUsers.UserDetails
    SET PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA_512', @pssWd + CAST((SELECT Salt FROM SiteUsers.UserDetails where UserName = @userNm) AS nvarchar(36)))
    WHERE UserName = @userNm
END
```

When I try to execute it I get the following error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure rtyfc_ChangePassword, Line 14 [Batch  Start Line 2]
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PasswordHash', table 'RostonTownYouthDB.SiteUsers.UserDetails'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

The stored procedure is supposed to update the password column in the database but its telling me I'm trying to insert a null value. I don't think I am but obviously I am I just cant see where or how. Any suggestion that point me towards a resolution would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**your HASHBYTES return null value that's why getting this error**

this function return null value

```
==>  `**HASHBYTES('SHA_512', @pssWd + CAST((SELECT Salt FROM SiteUsers.UserDetails where UserName = @userNm) AS nvarchar(36)))**`
```

and your field PasswordHash not nullable thats why geeting this error

**try this**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SiteUsers].[rtyfc_ChangePassword]
    (@userNm varchar(100),
     @pssWd nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE SiteUsers.UserDetails
    SET PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pssWd + CAST((SELECT Salt FROM SiteUsers.UserDetails where UserName = @userNm) AS nvarchar(36)))
    WHERE UserName = @userNm
END
```

Comment: Is the select wrapped in cast whats causing the null value?

Comment: I have update my answer please check and run sp again

Comment: +1 for answer - for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql